# ionic3 and angular HttpErrorResponse jsonp

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, jsonp

I have a little problem, I don't know what is it  . l try to get data information for schedule airport data json using ionic3 and angular . The code working fine , but the problem is when i run code for test and show console in chrome i get 'HttpErrorResponse ' .

[image: See image]

reddit-data.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class RedditDataProvider {

    private appId='common/v1/airport.json?';
    private baseUrl = 'https://XXXXXXXXXX.com/common/v1/airport.json?code=';

    constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
        console.log('Hello RedditData Provider');
    }


     city(city: string, country: string) {

         let url=this.baseUrl;
         url +=country;


         return this.http.jsonp(url,'callback');
     }

}
```

class home

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController,ModalController  } from 'ionic-angular';
import { RedditDataProvider } from '../../providers/reddit-data/reddit-data';
import {AddPage} from '../../pages/add/add';
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',

})
export class HomePage {

    public weatherList =[]

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController ,public redditService: RedditDataProvider
  ,private modal:ModalController) {}



 addWeather(){

    const myModal = this.modal.create('AddPage');

    myModal.onDidDismiss( (data) => {
            if (data) {
            this.getWeather(data.city, data.country);
        }   

    });

        myModal.present();  

} 

      getWeather(city: string, country: string){
        this.redditService.city(city, country)

          .subscribe(data => {

            this.weatherList.push(data);  
               console.log(data);
          },err => console.log(err),()=> 
          console.log('get'))

      }
      viewForecast(cityWeather){

          console.log( 'view forcast');

      }

}
```

the problem is with JSONP , status error "JSONP Error" . l try other server l get same problem . any solution please .

Comment: If you check in the network tab of the developer tools, can you see the response that's coming back? It looks like you're getting an error status back

Comment: it's same status error "JSONP Error"

Comment: As the response body?

Comment: no , same error in image i attached

Comment: Can you share the URL to allow us to reproduce the error, or does it need to remain hidden?

Comment: l hope , but have to remain hidden . l changed the url . i mean i use it another url same problem

Comment: If you're able to create a StackBlitz that reproduces the issue, that would be very helpful